# Find the y-intercept. Separable Equations.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**The Question**

Find the y-intercept of the curve that passes through the point (2,1) with the slope at (x,y) of $\frac{-9}{y^2}$

**My Work**

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-9}{y^2}$

$\int y^2dy = \int -9dx$

$\frac{y^3}{3} = -9x + C_1$

$y^3 = -27x + C$ (C =3C_1)

$y = (-27x + C)^{1/3}$

$1 = (-27(2) + C)^{1/3}$

$C = 54$

$0 = (-27x + 54)^{1/3}$

$y-intercept = (-2,0)$

I got the answer wrong, can anyone point out my mistake and give me a hint on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've miscalculated when finding your $C.$ When plugging $(x,y)=(2,1)$ into the equation $y^3=-27x+C$ (there's no need to solve for $y$ first, since the basic cubic function is invertible), we get $$1=-54+C,$$ whence....

Furthermore, you went on to use $54$ as your $C$ value, though you allegedly found $C=52.$ I suspect that at least one typo has been made.

Comment: I've adjusted by work and still can't find an answer. 55/27 is considered wrong.

Comment: nvm, go it, thanks for your help.

Comment: Good deal! (It seems you've realized that the problem was asking for the $y$-intercept, rather than the $x$-intercept.)